# Finding number of exact matches of string in file python

Tags: python

I have a question about how to find the number of exact matches of a string (specifically, a DNA sequence) in a file (specifically, a FASTA file) of strings. What I want to do is exactly like "grep -c "string" file_of_strings.fasta" from the command line. The code I have is below:

```
count = 0
for line in open("sequences.fasta"):
    if sequence in line:
        count += 1
```

This doesn't seem to be counting the number of instances of a particular string in my file, and I'm not exactly sure why. Any help would be much appreciated!

Well, so a fasta file is formatted as:

```
>SEQUENCE_1
MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG
LVSVKVSDDFTIAAMRPSYLSYEDLDMTFVENEYKALVAELEKENEERRRLKDPNKPEHK
IPQFASRKQLSDAILKEAEEKIKEELKAQGKPEKIWDNIIPGKMNSFIADNSQLDSKLTL
MGQFYVMDDKKTVEQVIAEKEKEFGGKIKIVEFICFEVGEGLEKKTEDFAAEVAAQL
>SEQUENCE_2
SATVSEINSETDFVAKNDQFIALTKDTTAHIQSNSLQSVEELHSSTINGVKFEEYLKSQI
ATIGENLVVRRFATLKAGANGVVNGYIHTNGRVGVVIAAACDSAEVASKSRDLLRQICMH
```

Comment: hmm seems right.. You are not looking for substrings right?

Comment: Are you assuming there is only 1 occurrence per line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('file') as f:
    print(f.read().count(sequence))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expression (if you are not assuming one match per line, your code assumes one match per line):

```
import re
f = open("sequences.fasta")
print len(re.findall(sequence, f.read()))
f.close()
```

1. Read the file as strings
2. look for matches using re.findall which would return list containing the matches
3. calculate the length of list from step 2.